# Implementing lazy evaluation for `reduceRight()` function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lazy-evaluation

A problem in the codewars.com: 
https://www.codewars.com/kata/foldr/train/javascript

Define a foldr function for array which implement the same function like built-in function reduceRight(). The problem is very abstract because I knew few about functional programming.

I find the most important is how to implement lazy-evaluation in the JavaScript. But I don't know how to deal with it.

For example, we have two functions, `indexOf` and `logging`, `indexOf(x)` is a function which will be called as arguments in the `foldr` method, `logging` is a wrapper function which tell us how many times `indexOf(x)` could be called.

```
const indexOf = y => function (cur, acc) {
  if (cur === y) {
    return 0
  } else {
    return acc + 1 || -1
  }
};

const logging = fn => function logging(...a) {
  i++;
  return fn(...a);
};
```

If we implement it without laziness and use recursion:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "foldr", {
  value: function foldr(fn, z) {
    return function _foldr(a) {
      if (a.length === 0) {
        return z
      }
      return fn(a[0], _foldr(a.slice(1)))
    }(this);
  }
});
let i = 0
let x = [1, 2, 3].foldr(logging(indexOf(1)), -1)
console.log(`x: ${x}`) // x: 0
console.log(`i: ${i}`) // i: 3
```

The variable `i` shows that the function has been called 3 times, the whole array has been iterated. However, if we observe the `indexOf` funciton we'll find that we don't need to iterate the whole array if we use lazy evaluation.

In the first level of recursion 
`indexOf(1)(a[0], _foldr(a.slice(1)))` equals `indexOf(1)(1, _foldr([2,3]))`, because `cur === y`, it should return 0 immediately and doesn't need to evaluate the second argument `_foldr([2,3])`. So in the test case of the codewars.com, the `i`  should be 1.

How could I deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You are close ...:

```
  fn(a[0], () => _foldr(a.slice(1)))
```

If you pass a function instead of the `acc`umulator value, the function can decide to evaluate the accumulator or not:

```
  const indexOf = y => function (cur, acc) {
    if (cur === y) {
      return 0; // acc() was not called, ends here
    } else {
      return acc() + 1 || -1; // acc() gets called, traversal goes on
    }
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I know this solution. But the question is that the `indexOf` is just an example of test cases. We don't know the content of it and can't modify its content. We only know the function has two arguments, the first is current value and the second is accumulate value, just like the `reduce` and `reduceRight` function.

Comment: Thats impossible. You need some way to signal the end of traversal.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution. Use `Object.prototype.valueOf()`

> The valueOf() method returns the primitive value of the specified object.

Because we'd like to call the function when we do some algorithms such as `return acc + 1 || -1`.

We could use:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'foldr', {
  value(fn, z) {
      let _foldr = (a) => {
          if (!a.length) return z;
          let r = fn(a[0], { valueOf: () => _foldr(a.slice(1)) });
          return (r.valueOf) ? r.valueOf() : r;
      };
      return _foldr(this);
  },
});
```